# Inconsistent serialization results of DateTime when using API

Tags: c#, odata, aspnetboilerplate

We save records with a datetime column in a SQL Server database. We get different results when using the OData API, depending on the usage.

Suppose there is a record with Id 23415 and a StartDateTime value saved as UTC 2019-04-08 05:15:00.000

- First way, get record 23415 using a select

  ```
  /Odata/XXXXX(23415)?$select=StartDateTime
  StartDateTime "2019-04-08T05:15:00+02:00"
  ```
- Second way, get record **without** a select

  ```
  /Odata/XXXXX(23415)
  StartDateTime "2019-04-08T07:15:00+02:00"
  ```

The results have inconsistent timezone mapping, how can this problem be solved, without creating a new customized OData serializer. Can it be configured in the aspnetboilerplate framework.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: create an issue https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/new

Comment: An issue has been created: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4453

Comment: great, track the issue from GitHub now.